# Compare a real object with a 3D model object in Unity AR Foundation/Arkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

My AR project is using Unity AR Foundation (**ArKit** - target **IOS**)
My project has a new feature: compares a real object with a 3D model is imported by user 
Example:

1. User imports a 3D apple model

2. He scans a real apple

3. The application will display: "This is an apple"

Has the UnityAR Foundation/Arkit been possible?
And if impossible, maybe we will need to code from ios native, so anybody has any idea/information about it?
I know that Vuforia may do it but we don't plan using it in the future

Comment: The question is very unclear. What exactly are you asking? Can you add links to the feature you are referring to?

Comment: @bpedazur This is a new feature in my AR project whose steps mentioned with the above example. And summarize, how can I do this with Unity AR Foundation or Unity ARkit plugin